# Decomposition of a Vector Space Into Invariant Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A: \mathbb{R}^6 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^6$ be a linear transformation such that $A^{26} = I$. Show that $\mathbb{R}^6 = V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_3$ where $V_1, V_2, V_3$ are two-dimensional invariant subspaces for $A$.

Comment: Think eigenvectors.

Comment: Lord Shark - can you elaborate? I always appreciate your input but your hints are too subtle for someone as dense as myself....

Comment: Hint: the minimal polynomial divides every polynomial that annihilates $A$. You know $\lambda^{26}-1$ annihilates $A$. Also, the minimal polynomial has degree at most $6$. So...